# Replacing frequently used complicated test in SQL Server Query with Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a test I have to use regularly in queries to see if a CPT billing code is a billable encounter. In the SQL query, the test looks like this:

```
where (pvp.code between '99201' and '99215'
    or pvp.code between '99221' and '99239')
```

plus a whole bunch more ranges.

I tried to create a function by just plugging this in to the function, but I got an "incorrect syntax" error -- not a huge surprise, really.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsEncounter 
(
    @code varchar(20)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result bit;

    SELECT @Result = @code between '99201' and '99215'
            or @code between '99221' and '99239';

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result;

END
```

I suppose I can do something like

```
if (@code >= '99201' and @code <= '99215')
        or (@code >= '99221' and @code <= '99239')
    select @Result = 1
else
    select @Result = 0;
```

but I'd like to know the cleanest way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that you create a table of start & end ranges, then your function could simply select count() from that table where @Code BETWEEN the tables start and end ranges, assuming you dont have overlapping ranges, COUNT() should only return 0 or 1 - easily cast to a BIT?

Comment: Interesting thought, but I'd just as soon keep it in code so I don't have to look multiple places to find out what the code does.

Comment: Thanks for the help, folks. I can write SELECT statements just fine, but as I get further into the DDL, things get hazy. :-)

Comment: Followup question, if anyone knows offhand. I'm storing this in a separate database, so I'll have to call it as abcd.dbo.IsEncounter(). I tried to do abcd..IsEncounter(), but it didn't like that. Is that something I can change, or just have to live with? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsEncounter 
(
   @code varchar(20)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result bit

    SET @Result = CASE WHEN (@code between '99201' and '99215') or (@code between '99221' and '99239') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are almost right with your UDF. I think there is just a few syntax issues. Try the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsEncounter 
(
    @code varchar(20)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result bit = 0

    IF @code between '99201' and '99215' or @code between '99221' and '99239'
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1
    END

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Then your WHERE clause would simply be:

```
where dbo.IsEncounter(p.Code)=1
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the CASE syntax suggested below, but this would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd move my ranges into a table and then do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsEncounter ( @code VARCHAR(20) )
RETURNS BIT
AS 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @MatchedRanges SMALLINT ;
        DECLARE @Result BIT ;

        SELECT  @MatchedRanges = COUNT(*)
        FROM    tblRangeWhiteList
        WHERE   @code BETWEEN RangeStart AND RangeEnd

        IF @MatchedRanges > 0 
            SET @Result = 1
        ELSE 
            SET @Result = 0

        RETURN @Result 

    END
```

Comment: As someone who works in healthcare, like the OP, this would quickly become a maintenance nightmare with the way CPT codes are administered.

Comment: Indeed, so having the ranges in a table would be preferable to editing SQL code all the time to include revised ranges.

Comment: CPT codes don't change that frequently.  But they are typically not congruent, e.g. From 100 - 200 but skip 151.  So at that point you have to complicate your table and logic to achieve what you think is simpler.  Where in this case, you can create a function that says "Give me all the billable CPT's" and you stuff all your logic into it and you rarely change that logic.  Healthcare Billing get's further complicated with HCPCS.  So in this case, you could have a function that says, "Is this procedure billable?".  I know it's not pretty, but that's the way it works sometimes.